# UIImage imageNamed returning nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, null, uiimage, xcode6

`UIImage` imageNamed returning nil in xcode 6 on iphone 6 simulator.. but perfectly works on xcode 5

code:

```
UIImage *img=[UIImage imageNamed@"img@2x~ipad"];
```

Comment: you you are using extra @2x… in your “method"? try just ..imageNamed:@“img”..

Comment: In my app, i am using only two image type .png and @2x~ipad.png!

Comment: that's why i explicitly mentioned the image name with extension in code

Comment: Does not matter that you have not the picture ...You must use only the “img”.. or “img.png” name; Using your “method”… the OS can search the wrong image: it will automatically bring @2x-ipad extension... and will search this image: img @ 2x ~ iPad @ 2x ~ ipad.png

Comment: @TonyMkenu: Thnx for rply. But i am using this @2x~ipad.png image in retina ipad, iphone 5 and iphone 6. That's why i explicityly mentioned this extension in code

Comment: iOS does automagic things with the `@2x` and the `~ipad` in the file name. It will auto-select the file, based on the name and the device type. If you don't want this behavior, name it something else. (You should keep the `@2x` if you want it to be correctly interpreted as Retina, however.)

Answer (score 2):

try

```
 UIImage *img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"img@2x~ipad.png"];
```